# If X is metrisable then X is Hausdorf

Tags: general-topology, analysis, solution-verification

**Let X be a topological space. If X is metrisable then X is Hausdorff.**
My proof:

*Suppose X is metrisable then there exists a metric d on X such that the topology on X is induced by d.

Then $d(x,y) > 0, \forall x, y \in X, x \neq y$.

Suppose this distance is $2\epsilon$ for some arbitrary distinct $x, y$.

Then consider the epsilon ball of each, that is, $B_{\epsilon}(x), B_{\epsilon}(y)$ both open in the metric topology induced by d.

Where we define $B_{\epsilon}(a) = \{ b \in X | d(a,b) < \epsilon\}$ for some $a \in X$

Since $d(x,y) = 2\epsilon$ we have that $B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap B_{\epsilon}(y) = \emptyset$

Hence for two arbitrary distinct points in $X$ we have constructed a disjoint open set for each of them.

We conclude that X is Hausdorff.*

**Is my proof correct and or does it need more explanation?**
**Thank you very much.**

Comment: Let $x\neq y$. Take $r=\frac12 d(x,y)$. The balls $B(x;r)$ and $B(y;r)$ do not intersect.

Comment: @OliverDiaz  That's what OP said as well.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to include in your proof an explanation of why in fact $B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap B_{\epsilon}(y)$ is the empty set, using the triangle inequality.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will include that.

Answer (score 0):

your proof does look correct. If you wanted to take this proof one step further, you can prove additional properties about $X$, given that it is metrizable.

1. Given a point $x$ and a closed set $A$, where $x \not\in A$, there exists disjoint open sets that contain $x$ and $A$.
2. Given disjoin closed sets $A$ and $B$, there exists disjoint open sets that contain $A$ and $B$.

The first property is known as a Regular space, and the second property is known as a Normal space. In the context of point-set topology, having a metric is very powerful.